# Could not load file or assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-jss

I am getting below error
[image]

I added "sitecore.kernel" using Nuget package manager also. But dont know what to dio next. I am Front end, not having much idea on this. Please help me.

In Visual studio 2022 used below command

PM> Install-Package Sitecore.Kernel -Version 10.2.0 -Source
https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json

Answer (score 0):

- Have you verify sitecore.kernel dll is present in your references as well as published to root directory [image]

[image]